# Has anyone written about filtered Tannakian categories?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, motives, tannakian-category, filtrations

tl;dr Is there any source that discusses the concept of a filtered Tannakian category? I'm writing a paper with this notion and want to know if it's ever been discussed.

The original book by Saavedra-Rivano discusses the notion of a filtration on a fiber functor. This applies to both the weight filtration and Hodge filtration for categories such as mixed Hodge structures and more generally anything related to mixed motives (systems of realizations, Mixed Tate motives, etc).

But the weight filtration has a further property: it is a filtration not just of the fiber but of the underlying object of the category (which is *not* true of the Hodge filtration). This should lead to the notion of a filtered Tannakian category, independent of a fiber functor.

The basic idea is pretty simple: a filtration on a Tannakian category means a filtration on every object that's preserved by morphisms (equivalently, a sequence of subfunctors of the identity functor), along with the properties that the filtration on every object is exhaustive and that it's compatible with the tensor product.

I'm developing the theory in a paper I'm writing, but I wanted to know if this concept has already been defined and discussed? It surprises me that I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: (DG-)categories with a structure of filtration is briefly discussed in §5 of [Ben-Zvi–Gunningham, Symmetries of categorical representations and the quantum Ngô action](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01963), and a more complete exposition in [Lurie, Rotation invariance in algebraic K-theory](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/Waldhaus.pdf) where it is called a *local filtration* (Def 3.1.10).

Comment: I believe that something of this sort was studied in much detail. One of the related terms is the motivic Galois group. You may try to read some texts of J. Ayoub.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Yes I'm very familiar with motivic Galois groups - that's what I'm applying this to in fact!

Comment: I would suggest that an (appropriately defined) weight filtration on a Tannakian category is unique and can be recovered from the Tannakian data. Possibly, some additional assumptions on the category are needed to make this statement valid.

Comment: Just a phrase from https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1423.14059 "Thanks to the Tannakian formalism it is equivalent to the category of graded comodules over a commutative graded Hopf algebra...":)